# Django All-Auth not redirecting to LOGIN_URL

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have all-auth setup and working, however I cannot get the LOGIN_URL to work and redirect to '/accounts/login/' as the default view by overriding the all-auth login template.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

If I go to localhost/accounts/login, I can get the page fine, however I am not able to get the above working in having it be the default location when localhost is visited.

I may be misunderstanding the docs and how it is supposed to be working.

looking to get it to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/` as the main page when localhost is visited.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #allauth urls
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    path('', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')
```

login.html (all-auth template override)

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}Login{% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
  </div>
  <form id="login_form" class="small" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      {% if redirect_field_value %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
      {% endif %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block" role="button">
      <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Login with Google
  </a>
  <a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' %}" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block" role="button">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
  </a>
  <hr>
  <div class="text-center">
      <a class="small" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
      <a class="small" href="#">Create an Account!</a>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Can you post the `urls.py` and `views.py` for the root route ( `/` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just figured out the mistake.  I was trying to create a url and view for getting at the login page, when all you need to do is create a view and url for the main app page, for example base.html, and then put a @login_required decorator on it.  When you try to navigate to the app and are not logged in, it redirects to the login template for all-auth.

final config below:

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.base, name='base'),
]
```